# How to check whether an app or dmg is signed or not?

Tags: java, codesign

I have created app and dmg for a Java application. I am signing as well as verifying dmg and app via codesign.

**codesign -s "mycomapany name" myproduct.dmg/myproduct.app**

Verifying both using following command -

**codesign -v myproduct.dmg/myproduct.app**

On executing this command for app and dmg separately it is not giving any message to confirm whether they are signed or not?

Like executing command - **jarsigner -verify -certs myproduct.jar** returns that "*jar verified*."

How can I verify that dmg and app are signed properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get more output from the `codesign` command, add a second `-v` argument after the first one:

```
codesign -v -v myproduct.dmg/myproduct.app
```

This is equivalent to:

```
codesign --verify --verbose myproduct.dmg/myproduct.app
```

The `codesign` command also has an exit value that you can use to get its result:

Examples for signed app:

```
codesign -v myproduct.dmg/myproduct.app
echo $?
Output: 0

codesign -v myproduct.dmg/myproduct.app && echo SIGNED!
Output: SIGNED!

codesign -v myproduct.dmg/myproduct.app || echo UNSIGNED!
No output
```

Examples for unsigned app:

```
codesign -v myproduct.dmg/unsigned.app
echo $?
Output: 1

codesign -v myproduct.dmg/unsigned.app && echo SIGNED!
No output

codesign -v myproduct.dmg/unsigned.app || echo UNSIGNED!
Output: UNSIGNED!
```

Comment: For those new to this - the myproduct.dmg/myproduct.app should be read as one of the two. So, if you have myproduct.dmg that contains an app named myproduct.app, then you will need to verify those separately. Eg: codesign -v myproduct.dmg && echo SIGNED! and then another request after mounting the dmg to verify the app, codesign -v myproduct.app && echo SIGNED!